# PHP Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Update\Status' not found

Tags: php, cron

My cron job is running but i am still getting these errors in error_log file.

PHP Fatal error: Class 'Magento\Update\Status' not found in /update/cron.php on line 15

and when i am installing any module then i am getting error at readiness check step cron job not set and other php errors while cron job is running.